# How to hide Windows Treeview control node's icon?

Tags: winapi, treeview

Sample code:

```
HIMAGELIST himl;  // handle to image list 
HBITMAP hbmp;     // handle to bitmap 

// Create the image list. 
if ((himl = ImageList_Create(16, 16,
    ILC_COLOR32, 1, 0)) == NULL)
    return ;

// Add the open file, closed file, and document bitmaps. 
hbmp = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_FOLDER));
if (-1 == ImageList_Add(himl, hbmp, (HBITMAP)NULL))
    return;
DeleteObject(hbmp);
if (ImageList_GetImageCount(himl) < 1)
    return;

// Associate the image list with the tree-view control. 
TreeView_SetImageList(hTree, himl, TVSIL_NORMAL);

//init normal books
tvs.hInsertAfter = NULL;
tvs.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
tvs.item.pszText = L"Notebook";
tvs.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
HTREEITEM rootItem = TreeView_InsertItem(hTree, &tvs);
```

The problem is: I do not set the `TVIF_IMAGE` or `TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE` mask, but the result treeview still contains the icon as follows:

[image: incorrect treeview result]

How could I hide this icon?

Comment: Once a treeview has an image list every item has to have an image. Your options are custom draw or to add an empty image to the image list.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: could you post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the folder because the folder icon you added is at positon 0 in the image list and when you create the TVINSERTSTRUCT to add the item, all values are reset to 0.

If you don't want it to display the icon either a) move the icon to position 1 or b) set the image indexes to the size of your bitmap + 1;